# How to overwrite Paragraphs Item on subpages?

Tags: theming

I am using a couple of Drupal Paragraphs Items in full-size edge-to-edge view with Bootrap’s container class. It’s working great.

I’ve applied a container class to paragraphs-item--service.tpl.php

However how can I overwrite the paragraph item on a subpage that uses a 2 column layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting it into the template, a better solution would be to use the [hook_entity_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/7.x) to add the classes based on some conditions.